# Storing sensitive data in android keychain

Tags: android, keystore, keychain

Wondering if I can save sensitive data in android keychain, and if I can access it from my other app that provides the correct set of credentials. Could find any straight forward and simple to follow tutorial on this area. Could someone share their insight on this. I'm looking for functionality similar to iOS Keychain.